# VSO - Source Code isn't downloading to Build Agent although no build failure

Tags: azure-pipelines, build-agent

I have a build agent installed on a server running as 'VSTSBuildAgent' account. 
I am currently using this build agent to run scheduled releases in VS GIT every day with no issue.

However now I am trying to build code that's in my team foundation version control repository.

I have selected my project and selected which mapping I want.

[image: VSO Source Mapping]

I've made sure that the build agent user has permissions to the Trunk branch, and made sure it has build permissions ext.

When I run the build I get the following output;
[image: Build Output]

However when I look on the server in the build agent files, the folder

C:\VSTSAgent_work\3\s

There's nothing there.

Any suggestions as to what I'm missing?

Comment: Go to version control security page (https://[account].visualstudio.com/[project]/_admin/_versioncontrol) and check Project Collection Build Service and  Project Collection Build Service Accounts permission (Read)

Comment: Only Project Collection Build Service Accounts group exists the first one doesn't, the account has read permissions and i've even added the build agent user to the group and given it all the permissions. Still not working

Comment: 1. What's the result if you queue build with Hosted Build agent? 2. Try to add Project Collection Build Service account to team project (Version control > Add > Add User> Select Project Collection Build Service) 3. Try to change build account to Network Service.

Comment: Also, try to go to version control security page, then select 3Sys folder > Click Inheritance > Check selected option (On or Off), also check this folder's permission.

Comment: @starain-MSFT   Hello, I added the account you suggested to the admin version control area and gave it permissions and it fixed the issue, if you write it as an answer i'll mark is as correct